# add jbutton over jtable

Tags: java, button, user-interface, layer

How can I add a jbutton over the cell area? this is the cleansheets app and I have to add a jbutton over the cell area( not inside of the cell) and I have no ideia how to do this. I tried to play with JLayeredPane but with no luck so far

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYK4i.jpg

Answer (score 0):

All Swing components extend from `Container`, so you can add any component to the JTable. The key is to set the bounds of the component. Something like:

```
Rectangle cell = table.getCellRect(....);
JButton button = new JButton(...);
button.setBounds( cell );
table.add( button );
table.repaint();
```

Comment: I cant add anythng to the cell itself. I have to create a panel over the table to add the buttons. also i have to position the button where the mouse is clicked

Comment: This does not add anything to the cell. The cell is NOT a real component, it is just painted to look like a cell. You can add a real component anywhere in the JTable using code like I provided you. The component will paint on top of the table, which means it paints on top of the cell. If you want it at the mouse click, then use the information from the MouseEvent to determine the location of the component.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work in here. This is the javadoc for the app if it helps http://csheets.sourceforge.net/api/

Comment: @user3079785, sure the solution works. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. That is create a JFrame with a JTable and add a JButton to the table. The entire code should be about 20 lines of code. Test the concept in a simple example like this to show that it works. Once you get this working, then you add the MouseListener to the code to test dynamic placement of the button. Finally you add the logic to your real app once you understand how the approach works.